# .NET Core project that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1 fails to load unmanaged assemblies from NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple .NET Core console application that targets `netcoreapp2.0` and `net461`. This application references a NuGet package:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0; net461</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.native.Company.Project" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The NuGet package contains a number of native dll files in the `runtimes\win7-x64` directory.

The application should be able to use P/Invoke to call the unmanaged code from the NuGet package:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        scsql_free_memory();
    }

    [DllImport("scsqlprocessor")]
    public static extern uint scsql_free_memory();
}
```

This works fine when using `netcoreapp2.0`: `dotnet run -f netcoreapp2.0`. With `net461`, it fails:

```
> dotnet run -f net461
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 15.89 ms for C:\Users\User\Desktop\reproduce\src\Reproduce.csproj.

Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'scsqlprocessor': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Program.scsql_free_memory()
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It seems like the unmanaged assemblies are not loaded with `net461`. I'm suspecting that this is because of how .NET Framework loads assemblies on demand. Does this mean that I have to manually load the unmanaged assemblies? If so, is there a way to do that in a way that works cross-platform?

Comment: It is not a loading problem, just a basic "file not found" error.  That does get murky when you use dotnet.exe, the OS doesn't know any better than it needs to look in the directory where dotnet.exe is stored.  Copy it there and see if that now solves the issue.  Clearly you'd then prefer a standalone exe in this case.  Or just plain building the version that doesn't use .netcore at all.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for your answer. When you say "copy it there", what do you mean should be copied? 

Why does the OS search for assemblies differently when using netcoreapp2.0 vs net461? Does netcoreapp2.0 hint the OS on where to find the assemblies? dotnet.exe is used in both cases.